# Code explanation - array of arrays stored in php $GLOBALS variable

Tags: php, arrays, global

I am learning the principles of an OOP based login/logout system (by phpacademy on YT). Here is the code that is giving me headache:

```
$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
    'init' = array(
        'hostname' = "127.0.0.1",
        'username' = 'root',
        'password' = '',
        'db' = 'dbName'
    ),
    'remember' = array(
        'cookie_name' = 'hash',
        'cookie_expiry' = 604800
    ),
    'session' = array(
        'session_name' = 'user'
    )
);

spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
});
```

This is obviously an array of arrays, with various bits of info needed to initialize a session and connect to the DB stored in these "sub-arrays".

What I can't wrap my head around is the beginning - he is obviously storing this array of arrays in a $GLOBALS variable; what is the ['config'] part?

1. regular variable has $variableName (so => "GLOBALS)
2. regular variable has scope, type and value (so => array();)

What is than thi in-between "[]"? Variable name? Declaration that what follows is an array (why the word array then, after the "="?)

Many thanks!

Comment: See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php  Specifically: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing and http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$GLOBALS` is an array.  It's an array of all global variables in your PHP script.  `['config']` is how you access elements in an array in PHP.

In the `$GLOBALS` array, he is setting the `'config'` key to an array.  That array contains 3 keys: `'init'`, `'remember'`, and `'session'`.

Comment: So basically, it is the same as if he did:$GLOBALS[0]=1; $GLOBALS[1]=whatever; $GLOBALS[3]=...? A-haa! Eureka moment :)

Comment: @AlexStarbuck: Yeah, but he used `'config'` as a key instead of `0`, and the value is an array :)

Comment: Thanks man! Just one of those situations where you get stuck and its SO simple! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to learn the difference between an indexed array and an associative array. In Php, you can define an `array` two ways. The first is the simple array:

```
$array = array("1", "2", "3");
```

This would create an index array (index being 0 - n for length of the array) which you can access like so:

```
echo $array[0]; // Would echo "1"
```

Pretty straight forward now? The next type of array you can declare is an associative array:

```
$array = array("one" => "1", "two" => "2", "three" => "3");
```

This array is set up slightly differently. Instead of starting at 0 and adding 1 for every element in the array, you define a `key => value` pair for the array, and access any element using that `key` value:

```
echo $array["one"]; // Would echo "1"
```

Essentially, `$GLOBALS` is an array, and `$GLOBALS["config"]` is an associative entry in this array that can be accessed any time using the `config` key. Hope that made sense. Check the php manual for more information on arrays and their usage:

[PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, much appreciated! I have actually read and learned basic types of arrays :) but this one is giving me trouble. By analogy, GLOBALS array should have a couple of key/value pairs, where one of them has the key "config". This one has three keys: init, remember and session. That's why the confusion

Comment: @AlexStarbuck: The `$GLOBALS` will have other key/value pairs, yes.  It contains all the global variables in your script (with the variable name as the key).

Answer (score 0):

php.net is short, but detailed enough about it: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `config` is an array index. Namely a top level index for the `$GLOBALS` array.

You can use `print_r($GLOBALS)` or `var_dump($GLOBALS)` to see a nice representation of the array structure.